# ¿La palabra "español" en el logotipo debe usar la mayúscula inicial o no?

Tags: discusión

Esto es nuestro logotipo, con la palabra "español" escrita con la primera letra mayúscula:

[image: stackoverflow en Español]

No soy un hablante nativo de español, y tal vez no recuerdo las reglas de capitalización correctamente, pero yo pensé que los nombres de idiomas en español no deben ser capitalizados, al contrario que inglés. ¿Es necesario cambiar el logo o no?

Answer (score 14):

Al parecer hay algunas fuentes que dicen que debe capitalizarse la primera letra y otras que dicen lo contrario, así que fui a la `RAE` y me encontré con [esto](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp):

> 6. Casos en que no debe usarse la mayúscula inicial. Se escriben con minúscula inicial, salvo que la mayúscula venga exigida por la puntuación (→ 3), las palabras siguientes:

...

> 6.7. Los nombres de tribus o pueblos y de lenguas, así como los gentilicios: el pueblo inca, los mayas, el español, los ingleses.

Así que sí, debería ir en minúsculas según entiendo.

Comment: Si respetamos las reglas al pie de la letra el nombre del idioma debería ir sin mayúscula. Faltaría ver si existe algún criterio mercadotécnico que haga deseable que esté con mayúsculas (en lo personal, me gusta *visualmente* cómo se ve con mayúscula... pero es un tema estético, no lingüistico). El sitio en portugués tiene el nombre del idioma con mayúscula; el sitio en ruso *parece tener* el nombre con minúscula (no sé ruso, así que lo infiero por el tamaño del caracter)... no parece haber una regla estándar al respecto

Comment: Por supuesto que va con minúscula! Para mí, lo escribieron con mayúscula por un error común: en inglés las lenguas se escriben con mayúsculas, pero no en español... Cuando lo vi con mayúscula me molestó, para mí debería estar con minúscula. Sin embargo, creo que es algo muy poco prioritario, y no me molestaría que sea lo último de la lista de cosas para modificar del sitio.

Comment: @Barranka Inferiste bien, en ruso las lenguas no se escriben con mayúsculas: es "Stack Overflow на русском", no "Stack Overflow на Русском".